# How can I fix `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a new command that sends the author a message, however, when the author's DMs is closed it's giving me the error `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user`

```
    if (!message.author.send) {
        return message.channel.send("DMs closed.");
    } else {
        message.author.send("DMs opened")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said the DM's for the author is closed, so it doesn't work. You can try something like this:

```
    //Put the messages you wanted to send the author's DM's
    //Add this below it
    .catch(error => {
          console.error(
            `Could not send help DM to ${message.author.tag}.\n`,
            error
          );
          message.reply("it seems like I can't DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?");
     });

     //If the user has the DM's turned off, then it'll send this in the channel and `console.log` the error
```

Answer (score 0):

the `send` function will always exists, even if the user dm is closed or open, to check if the dm is closed you can use `.catch` to catch the `DiscordAPIError` error.
See: [`Promise.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Try this:

```js
message.author.send("DMs opened").catch(error => message.channel.send("DMs closed"))
```